What is this video dithering effect called + how can i achieve this?
I'm going to make a vlog using this effect since I was looking for a LQ, Nokia-ish footage! What is this effect called and can it be achieved via After Effects? Thank you!


You can get close to this effect using Red Giant Shine and Glow plugins on the text, add a Lens Flare in the middle, then add an adjustment layer over all of it, with a Posterize plugin to reduce the number of colours used (about level 22 should do it), then a mosaic effect to reduce the effective resolution
not in any way perfect, but getting there, needs more noise and atmospheric light, mabye a lux plugin etc etc..

